# How can I run a Python script without source files on Raspbian?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, executable, desktop-application, raspbian

I developed a Python script on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, which runs on a Raspbian operating system. I would like my application to start by double clicking on a desktop icon. However this should work without needing the application source file. As happens when C programs are compiled, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library can help you there. I found a few guides, this one seems to be achieving what you are looking for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/